# Using Selenium with C# and Continuous Integration for a Web App requiring SSO (single sign on)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, single-sign-on

The web app I want to test require my company Single Sign On to access it.
I have a Selenium C# scenario with ChromeDriver, I would like to execute in my continuous integration system (separate servers).
It won't work because of single sign on. We have a 2 factors authentication policy so I can't even automate the authentication SSO part with selenium and I want to avoid storing a SSO password on my CI server.

Locally I bypass by using my local chrome options:

```
 ChromeOptions chroptions = new ChromeOptions();
 chroptions.AddArguments("--noerrdialogs");
 chroptions.AddArguments(@"user-data-dir=C:\Users\" + currentUser + @"\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data");
 chroptions.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
 chroptions.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
```

I know I could also just use a saved cookie (an the 2 factor security will still be an issue) but I will face the same problem.
Also for security it will expire after a time, so I would like to have a more reliable solution for Continuous Integration.
I know without knowing the details of my SSO it's difficult but did anyone encounter this situation and solve it ? (SSO and 2 factors authentication is more and more common)

Lionel

Comment: You need to persuade your company that to do the automated testing, the SSO server should have a specific login for testing, and that login doesn't require MFA.

Comment: Can you test your service using mocks for SSO? Do you really need a live third party service to do your tests and not mocks?

Comment: We want to test the web app as a black box and do automation in all of our environments so in live we can't really mock it. We already have other automation covering service automatically with mock up. I will investigate asking for a test SSO account.

Comment: Or can you log in through a web API in your test, then create the Google Chrome session with that login cookie?

Comment: And by "through a test" I mean using C#, call a web API to log in, which returns the login session info. From that, create a cookie that Chrome uses so it can piggy-back off the web API login session.